# Break string at an index

Tags: c#

I am  trying to break a string at position 4 and then save as another string. The substring works with simple A-Z letters but can you help me with this.

```
string messageToSend = "P0011%$1%$6%$1%$1%$Heat And Smoke Detector|1%$1%$7%$1%$1%$Sounder|1%$1%$9%$2%$1%$Input Device Zone 2|";

string myString = messageToSend.Substring(1, messageToSend.Length);
```

Comment: It throws argument out of range exception in Visual Studio 2010 when I try to execute it.

Comment: `messageToSend.Length - 1);`

Comment: If you start from position 1 to string.Length you always get OutOfRangeException. Set string.Length-1

Comment: or just `messageToSend.Substring(4);`  By default, the rest of the string will be returned.  there's no need to specify the length if you want everything from index 4 onward.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that, I actually need to break it at index 4. the code is now at  string myString = messageToSend.Substring(4, messageToSend.Length-1); but still throws an error

Comment: Expanding on @gunr2171 comment, the correct signature is `Substring(startIndex, length)`, and not `Substring(startIndex, endIndex)`.

Comment: @ps2goat - Thanks, that has solved it. Can you place it as the answer so I can close it. Thank you, couldn't find this information anywhere else.

Comment: You can use `messageToSend.Remove(4)` if you want to take only the first four characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has two signatures:

The one you are currently using is `Substring(int startIndex, int length)`.

Your code example at the top starts at index 1 (the second character), and goes "length of string" characters. The problem is this would go one character past the end of the string.

The easy fix for this situation is

```
string myString = messageToSend.Substring(1, messageToSend.Length - 1);
```

Note the `-1`. This will be the same as the "offset" value you are applying to the start of the string.

However, there is a much easier way to do this, and that's with the second form of the method: `Substring(int startIndex)`.

This only asks for the index to start at, and goes all the way to the end of the string. You don't have to worry how long the string it; it will take care of that for you.

Your example can be filtered down to this:

```
string myString = messageToSend.Substring(1);
```

Or, if you wanted to start at the 4th index:

```
string myString = messageToSend.Substring(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a length mismatch for the remainder of the string.  If you need the entire string after your specific index, just use this overload of `Substring`:

```
string messageToSend = "P0011%$1%$6%$1%$1%$Heat And Smoke Detector|1%$1%$7%$1%$1%$Sounder|1%$1%$9%$2%$1%$Input Device Zone 2|";

string myString = messageToSend.Substring(4);
```

If specifying the length, you'd need to account for the characters you removed from the string.

1. Index of 4 means 5 characters (indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4)
2. Length starts counting at one, not zero, so add one more to the number of characters to remove.
3. Total chars removed during your substring operation: 6

If specifying the length of the string to remove, the code would be:

```
string messageToSend = "P0011%$1%$6%$1%$1%$Heat And Smoke Detector|1%$1%$7%$1%$1%$Sounder|1%$1%$9%$2%$1%$Input Device Zone 2|";

string myString = messageToSend.Substring(1, messageToSend.Length - 6);
```

Comment: Let me guess, you saw the existing answer and said "I can do better than that"?

Comment: @gunr2171, no I answered it in the comments and the OP asked me to post it because I helped him.

Answer (score 0):

Set `string.Length - 1`

```
string messageToSend = "P0011%$1%$6%$1%$1%$Heat And Smoke Detector|1%$1%$7%$1%$1%$Sounder|1%$1%$9%$2%$1%$Input Device Zone 2|";

string myString = messageToSend.Substring(1, messageToSend.Length - 1);
```

Comment: I did make this change however it did not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @KamranAli, if you are specifying the length to return, it should be `string myString = messageToSend.Substring(4, messageToSend.Length - 6);`  (index of 4, or 0-4, is 5 characters.  the length property starts counting at one, not 0, so you need to remove one from length for that.  total to remove is 6 characters.